# Accessing hammer event info from Angular directive inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and I'm trying to get the XY coordinates of a tap using angular-hammer.js directives. Here's how the directives are set up:

```
var hmTouchevents = angular.module('hmTouchevents', []),
hmGestures = ['hmHold:hold',
              'hmTap:tap',
              'hmDoubletap:doubletap',
              'hmDrag:drag',
              'hmDragup:dragup',
              'hmDragdown:dragdown',
              'hmDragleft:dragleft',
              'hmDragright:dragright',
              'hmSwipe:swipe',
              'hmSwipeup:swipeup',
              'hmSwipedown:swipedown',
              'hmSwipeleft:swipeleft',
              'hmSwiperight:swiperight',
              'hmTransform:transform',
              'hmRotate:rotate',
              'hmPinch:pinch',
              'hmPinchin:pinchin',
              'hmPinchout:pinchout',
              'hmTouch:touch',
              'hmRelease:release'];

angular.forEach(hmGestures, function(name){
  var directive = name.split(':'),
  directiveName = directive[0],
  eventName = directive[1];
  hmTouchevents.directive(directiveName, ["$parse", function($parse) {
    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var fn, opts;
        fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
        opts = $parse(attr["hmOptions"])(scope, {});
        scope.hammer = scope.hammer || Hammer(element[0], opts);
        return scope.hammer.on(eventName, function(event) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            return fn(scope, {
              $event: event
            });
          });
        });
      }
    };
    }
  ]);
});
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl" >
    <div class='tap-area' hm-tap="tap();">
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
App.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, Myapp) {

$scope.tap = function(ev){
     //How do I get the event.gesture.center.pageX in here?
};

});
```

Comment: Is the tap method being called in the controller?

Comment: The tap method is being called by the directive on a tap event, but yes, that tap method is inside the IndexCtrl controller.

Comment: You callback is return `fn(scope,{$event:evemt})`. In the controller the function structure should be `$scope.tap=function(scope,evtobj)` Use the second parameter to get the event under `evtobj.$event`

Comment: That's what I though too... except evtobj is undefined. It's ok. The answer I gave below fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to make this work. After `return scope.hammer.on(eventName, function(event) {` I added `scope.event = event;` and then in my controller I can get XY coords of a tap by using `this.event.center.pageX` or `this.event.center.pageY`.

Answer (score 0):

It was posted long time ago but here is another solution.

Just add $event to your html

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference